# I cant get SevenZipLib library to work (p/invoke)

Tags: c#

Very basic knowledge on c# and is the first i use anything p/invoke related.

Help me pls, i have made this code but it doesnt seem to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("C:\\Users\\lchris\\Desktop\\SevenZipLib_9.13.2\\SevenZipLib\\SevenZipLib\\7z86.dll")]
        public static extern void SevenZipArchive(string c);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SevenZipArchive archive = new SevenZipArchive("file.rar"))
            {
                foreach (ArchiveEntry entry in archive)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(entry.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It tells me that SevenZipArchive is a 'Method' and is being used like a 'type'.

I have include the library to my project already, i just dont know how to use it.

Here is the library:
https://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/

Comment: [SevenZipSharp](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) is a manager wrapper for 7-Zip that takes care of the P/Invoke call for you.

Comment: @Douglas So does SevenZipLib

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're right. I assumed it was a native library from the OP's P/Invoke calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to remove this code:

```
[DllImport("...")]
public static extern void SevenZipArchive(string c);
```

You do not need to provide any p/invoke declarations. The library wraps that up for you.

This is a .net assembly. You use it just as you use any other. Take the following steps:

1. Download the project. You already did that I think.
2. Build the solution. Make sure that
3. In your project, add a reference to the assembly that you built in the previous stage. It's `SevenZipLib\bin\Debug\SevenZipLib.dll` or `SevenZipLib\bin\Release\SevenZipLib.dll` depending on the target you selected.
4. Add `using SevenZipLib;` to your project code to to gain access to the namespace.

Once you've done that your code will work. You can use the tests project that is supplied as part of the download as a rich source of example code.

Comment: thanks alot, i understand now. its showing a new error though, i updated my comment and maybe you can help me.

Comment: I reverted that edit. That's a different question. You didn't tell us the full error message though, which does not help. You need to make sure that the 7z DLLs 7z64.dll and 7z86.dll are located alongside the assembly SevenZipLib.dll.

Comment: that was the full error "Unable to find 7-zip Library". I fix it though, i was refferencing another folder by mistake.